# Meaning of L1 local store / L1 global read in Nvidia visual profiler

Tags: cuda

```
__global__ void kern (int* gpuArr) {
    int a;

    a = gpuArr[threadIdx.x+1];
}

int main(char** argv, int argc) {
    int* gpuArr;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuArr,628*sizeof(int));

    kern<<<1,32>>>(gpuArr);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

When profiling the code above in Nvidia visual profiler, i get the following memory bandwidth analysis.

[image]

As far as i can understand, what happens is:

Memory load from global - L2 miss

Copy 5*32B from global to L2 (I think that the cache row size of L2 always is 32B)

Copy 2*128B from L2 to L1 (including additional data from L2, since the L1 cache line is 128B?)

Do the equivalent of a = L1_position[threadIdx.x] for every thread

So where is the local variable "a" in each thread stored? According to the debugger it isn't in the registers (that usually shows up as @register int in the variables tab, but it says @local int instead). And what exactly does the line "Local Stores 1" mean? We already did 2*128B L2 to L1 copy ("Global Loads"), so what is the meaning of "Local Store". And why is there only 1 "Local Store" when there is 2 "Global Stores"?

Also, I'm using cc 3.0, so global memory caching in L1 is not possible according to specs

Comment: Are you using exactly that code for your measurement? The problem with your code is that `a = gpuArr[threadIdx.x+1];` will be optimized away completely as it does not alter the global state.

Comment: I am using that exact code, and I can debug it so I don't think it is being optimized away

Comment: @Obabopisamon: when you turn on debugging, compiler optimisation is disabled. But otherwise that kernel will be compiled to a NULL stub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as has already been pointed out:

1. You are running a code that has been compiled with the debug switch (`-G`).  This will not give you the best performance, and is not representative (either performance wise or behaviorally) of codes compiled without it, so profiling such code is a questionable activity.
2. Since `-G` disables compiler optimizations, such codes may not behave the way you expect.

> So where is the local variable "a" in each thread stored?

It is stored in the local logical space.  This is exactly what the profiler (and debugger) are telling you.  The "local" logical space can exist either in registers or in physical (on-board DRAM) memory.  The reason it is not in registers is because you have disabled optimizations with the `-G` switch, and such placement of logical data in a register is an optimization.  You won't be able to confirm this directly by eliminating the `-G` switch, because if you did so your code as written would be completely optimized away by the compiler, since it has no effect on any global state.

> And what exactly does the line "Local Stores 1" mean?

As discussed above, the variable `a` is in the local logical space, and so the read from global and the write to local occurring here:

```
a = gpuArr[threadIdx.x+1];
```

will cause a local store, when `a` is "written".

> And why is there only 1 "Local Store" when there is 2 "Global Stores"?

Variables stored in DRAM memory that belong to the local logical space will be stored in memory in such a way that successive access by threads in a warp will generate adjacent (i.e. "coalesced") access when the DRAM memory transaction is made, to read or write such values.  This means that if I have a local variable `a` for each thread, then `a` of thread 0 will be stored first, then `a` of thread 1, then `a` of thread 2, etc. so that if each thread reads (or writes) `a`, the resultant access will be coalesced.  Since you have exactly 1 warp of 32 threads, each writing an `int` value of `a`, this results in a single 128 byte local store transaction.

In your global memory case (i.e. the read), you have caused your read to step across a cacheline/segment boundary with the 1 added to your array index:

```
a = gpuArr[threadIdx.x+1];
                       ^
```

so it requires two global transactions to collect the data requested by the warp.  If you want to confirm this, eliminate the +1 on the array index and the global transactions should drop from 2 to 1.

As a caveat, profiling very small amounts of activity may not always give you the results you expect (although it seems to be working in this case).  The reason for this is that some profiler metrics are captured for some subset of SMs, and then multiplied by the number of SMs to reflect the full GPU activity.  If results for very small data sets don't make sense, you may get more sensible results for larger datasets that more appropriately "fill" the GPU with consistent activity across SMs.